# how does (=+ ) works in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this code and i dont know what does =+ means it does not work like += hence

x+=y adds y value to x but x=+ it looks like its replace x value with y value

```js
var counters= document.querySelectorAll('.counter'); 
counters.forEach(counter => {

    counter.innerText= '0' ; 
    const updateCounter = ()=> {
        const target =+ counter.getAttribute('data-target')
        const c = +counter.innerText
        const increasment = target/200;
        if(c<target) {
            counter.innerText = c+increasment ; 
            setTimeout(updateCounter,5)
        }
        else {
            counter.innerText=target 
        }
     
     
        
    }

    updateCounter(); 
})
```

Comment: `var x = 2`,  is no different to doing `var x = +2`,  does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is a separate operator from the assignment operator (`=`). It is a unary plus, which converts the operand to a number if it isn't one already. So it's basically just a short but not very readable way of saying

```
const c = Number(counter.innerText)
```